# Given an unordered array and a value v, what are the two numbers that added are equals to v

Tags: arrays

The array max size is 10^5
I can only imagine on trying every possibility, on a O(n^2) solution, there is a better way for solving that?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: How long does it take to create a sorted array?

Answer (score -1):

I've found the better solution on this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-that-given-a-set-a-of-n-numbers-and-another-number-x-determines-whether-or-not-there-exist-two-elements-in-s-whose-sum-is-exactly-x/

Comment: Please include a relevant snippet from the link as links often go bad and this answer will no longer have any value if that happens.